# JAXP Source and Result implementations for POJOs

Tags: java, xslt

Is anyone aware of implementations of the standard `javax.xml.transform.Source` and `javax.xml.transform.Result` which operate on underlying POJOs?

In other words, I want to use XSLT to transform one java object graph into another.

I am currently using xstream to render the POJOs to a W3C DOM, and then using `DomSource` and `DomResult` to pass to a `javax.xml.transform.Transformer`, but I'd like to skip that step and operate directly on POJOs, using the same XSLT and `Transformer`/`Source`/`Result` interfaces.

I'm already aware of Apache JXPath, which provides an XPath implementation which operates on POJOs, which is sort of halfway there, but not quite far enough.

Also, JAXB provides `javax.xml.bind.util.JAXBSource` and `JAXBResult`, but these only work on objects which are instances of JAXB-annotated classes.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried looking at [smooks](http://www.smooks.org)? It is able to mix XSLT and POJO transformations under one configuation file.

Comment: I just write a test case which uses a smooks `JavaSource` and `JavaResult`  and passing them to a Transformer, but the `Transformer` rejects the `JavaResult` because it's not a `DomResult`, a `StreamResult` or a `SAXResult` (which the Transformer API requires). It seems tantalisingly close, but I don't want to use the Smooks infrastructure, just its API.

Comment: But which Transformar API implementation are you using? I guess it is really dependent on the implementation which types of sources/results are supported. I guess you can make a wrapper around the library you are using and make it use JavaSource/JavaResult through smooks. But I'm only guessing here. Never done it myself :).